# CSS Selector throws timeout exception in Selenium script

Tags: python, selenium, css-selectors, webdriverwait

> Traceback (most recent call last):File
>   "C:\Users\PSWN672P\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Python
>   programs\SNOW1.py", line 17, in 
>       EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'ul[id*="collapseId"]>li:nth-child(5)>ul[id*="collapseId"]>li>div>a>div>div'))
>       File "C:\Users\PSWN672P\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py",
>   line 80, in until
>       raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
>       selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Trying to access the element with text as **My Groups Work** and run a script to automatically click that element and navigate to next page:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time


browser=webdriver.Ie()
browser.get('http://example.com')

try:

    window_before=browser.window_handles[0]
    element=WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'ul[id*="collapseId"]>li:nth-child(5)>ul[id*="collapseId"]>li>div>a>div>div')))
    element.click()
    time.sleep(15)
    window_after=browser.window_handles[1]
    browser.switch_to_window(window_after)

finally:

    browser.quit()
```

```html
<a class="sn-widget-list-item sn-widget-list-item_hidden-action module-node" id="2ccb50dfc61122820032728dcea648fe" href="task_list.do?sysparm_userpref_module=2ccb50dfc61122820032728dcea648fe&amp;sysparm_query=assignment_group=javascript:getMyGroups()^active=true^assigned_to=^sys_class_name!=cert_follow_on_task^sys_class_name!=sc_req_item^sys_class_name!=sc_request^EQ&amp;sysparm_clear_stack=true" target="gsft_main"><div class="sn-widget-list-content" data-id="2ccb50dfc61122820032728dcea648fe">
    <div class="sn-widget-list-content" data-id="2ccb50dfc61122820032728dcea648fe">
        <div class="sn-widget-list-title">My Groups Work</div>
    </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

why not just locate element by class name?

`element=WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME,'sn-widget-list-title')))`

Comment: I'm receiving this error now- "raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element is not displayed"

Answer (score 0):

CSS Selector throws timeout exception as the [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) which you have adapted doesn't identifies the desired element uniquely. Perhaps *TimeoutException* is the outcome of failed *ExpectedConditions*.
However, to `click()` on the element with text as "My Groups Work" you can use the following solution:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.sn-widget-list-item.sn-widget-list-item_hidden-action.module-node[href^='task_list.do?sysparm_userpref_module=']>div.sn-widget-list-content[data-id]>div.sn-widget-list-title")))
  ```

Alternative

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='sn-widget-list-item sn-widget-list-item_hidden-action module-node' and starts-with(@href,'task_list.do?sysparm_userpref_module=')]/div[@class='sn-widget-list-content' and (@data-id)]/div[@class='sn-widget-list-title' and contains(., 'My Groups Work')]")))
  ```

Note: You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```